# how to get orignal gnome on Ubuntu 18.04, with all the other software as in Ubuntu Gnome flavour?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell

I am a great fan of Ubuntu as well as gnome. Although i do not like the customized gnome shell in Ubuntu 18.04. Further more since the Ubuntu GNOME has been discontinued i would like to have an original gnome with gnome software and all the other software as if in Ubuntu GNOME. Kindly hep me get it back in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.